# Extra dummy components painted during thread execution

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

In a Java applet, I'm trying to slow down the painting of an image made up of parts, so I wrote a test program to get the basic concept working. I'm using a thread to draw a number of boxes one at a time instead of a timer because I want to be able to click the go button to reset the drawing process at any time.

The problem is, after drawing a box, it moves down a bit and an extra of the label shows up at the top of the screen. When the mouse moves off the button at the bottom, a dummy button  also shows up at the top of the screen. The dummy button doesn't respond to clicks (only the real one at the bottom does), it's just there.

I'm still pretty new at this, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here's the JApplet class:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;


public class TestDraw extends JApplet implements ActionListener
{
    private DrawPanel panel;
    private JLabel lbl1;
    JButton go;
    Thread t;

    public void init()
    {
        lbl1 = new JLabel("hi");

        go = new JButton("GO");
        go.addActionListener(this);

        panel = new DrawPanel();

        getContentPane().setBackground(Color.yellow); 

        add(lbl1, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(go, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
      // tried adding these. didnt help
      //panel.validate();
      //panel.repaint();
      //validate();

      panel.resetBoxes();
      repaint();
    }

    public void start(){
        t = new Thread(panel);
        t.start();
    }
}
```

Here's the DrawPanel Class:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import javax.swing.*;

public class DrawPanel extends JPanel implements Runnable
{
    private SecureRandom randGen = new SecureRandom();
    private Box[] boxes;
    private int box2draw = 0;

    public DrawPanel()
   {
       setBackground(Color.WHITE); 

       boxes = new Box[5];

       for (int count = 0; count < boxes.length; count++){
           int x = randGen.nextInt(300);
           int y = randGen.nextInt(300);
           int w = randGen.nextInt(300);
           int h = randGen.nextInt(300);

           Color color = new Color(randGen.nextInt(256), randGen.nextInt(256), randGen.nextInt(256));

           boxes[count] = new Box(x,y,w,h,color);
        }
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        boxes[box2draw].draw(g);
        box2draw++;
    }

    public void resetBoxes(){
        boxes = new Box[5];

       for (int count = 0; count < boxes.length; count++){
           int x = randGen.nextInt(300);
           int y = randGen.nextInt(300);
           int w = randGen.nextInt(300);
           int h = randGen.nextInt(300);

           Color color = new Color(randGen.nextInt(256), randGen.nextInt(256), randGen.nextInt(256));

           boxes[count] = new Box(x,y,w,h,color);
           box2draw = 0;
        }
    }

    public void run(){
        while(true){
            try{
                Thread.sleep(750);
            }
            catch(InterruptedException e){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "interrupted");
            }

            repaint();
        }
    }
}
```

And finally, the Box class:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;

public class Box
{
    private int x;
    private int y;
    private int w;
    private int h;
    private Color color;

    public Box(int x,int y,int w,int h,Color color)
    {
        // initialise instance variables
        this.x = x;
        this.y=y;
        this.w=w;
        this.h = h;
        this.color=color;
    }

    public void draw(Graphics g)
    {
        g.setColor(color);
        g.drawRect( x, y,  w, h);
    }
}
```

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problems:

- You've got code logic within a painting method -- something that you should never do -- including your incrementing an array index. You don't have full control of when or even if this method is called and so program logic does not belong there, just painting. If you need to increment your array index, do it elsewhere, perhaps within your thread's `while (true)` loop. Also take care not to have the index go beyond the size of the array.
- You never call the super's paintComponent method within your override, and this will prevent the component from doing housekeeping painting, probably your main problem.
- If you need to display multiple items, then consider either drawing to a BufferedImage and displaying that within paintComponent, or creating a collection of Shape objects and drawing all of them within paintComponent via a for-loop.
- I prefer to use the Swing-safer Swing Timer. While it doesn't matter if only calling `repaint()` if you want to make any other Swing calls intermittently, it makes life much easier and coding safer.

For example

```
package foo1;

import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Stroke;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class TestDraw2 {
    @SuppressWarnings("serial")
    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        final DrawPanel2 drawPanel = new DrawPanel2();

        JButton drawButton = new JButton(new AbstractAction("Draw!") {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                drawPanel.resetBoxes();
            }
        });
        JPanel btnPanel = new JPanel();
        btnPanel.add(drawButton);

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("TestDraw2");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(drawPanel);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGui();
            }
        });
    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class DrawPanel2 extends JPanel {

    private static final int BOX_COUNT = 5;
    private static final int TIMER_DELAY = 750;
    private static final int PREF_W = 600;
    private static final int PREF_H = PREF_W;
    private Random randGen = new Random();
    private Box[] boxes;
    private int box2draw = 0;

    public DrawPanel2() {
        setBackground(Color.YELLOW);

        boxes = new Box[BOX_COUNT];

        for (int count = 0; count < boxes.length; count++) {
            int x = randGen.nextInt(300);
            int y = randGen.nextInt(300);
            int w = randGen.nextInt(300);
            int h = randGen.nextInt(300);

            Color color = new Color(randGen.nextInt(256), randGen.nextInt(256),
                    randGen.nextInt(256));

            boxes[count] = new Box(x, y, w, h, color);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        if (isPreferredSizeSet()) {
            return super.getPreferredSize();
        }
        return new Dimension(PREF_W, PREF_H);
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        for (int i = 0; i < box2draw; i++) {
            boxes[i].draw(g);
        }
    }

    public void resetBoxes() {
        boxes = new Box[BOX_COUNT];

        for (int count = 0; count < boxes.length; count++) {
            int x = randGen.nextInt(300);
            int y = randGen.nextInt(300);
            int w = randGen.nextInt(300);
            int h = randGen.nextInt(300);

            Color color = new Color(randGen.nextInt(256), randGen.nextInt(256),
                    randGen.nextInt(256));

            boxes[count] = new Box(x, y, w, h, color);
            box2draw = 0;
        }
        repaint();

        new Timer(TIMER_DELAY, new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                box2draw++;
                if (box2draw > BOX_COUNT) {
                    box2draw = BOX_COUNT;
                    ((Timer) e.getSource()).stop();
                } 
                repaint();
            }
        }).start();
    }
}
```

Comment: Heh. .Congrats on hitting (a well deserved) 200K.  :)

Comment: Thank you! Thank you! Thank you! Sooooo much! That was just what it needed. It works exaclty the way I wanted now. You have taught me a couple of very valuable things. I don' t know how to thank you enough!

Comment: *"..not quite there yet."*  Oh, you're paying too much attention tot the 5 digit number.  It's the 3 digit 1 letter rep. that's important here.  ;)

Comment: @AndrewThompson: Yep, I'm riding that near-dead horse (Swing) into the StackOverflow sunset. Ha!

Comment: *"I'm riding that near-dead horse (Swing) into the StackOverflow sunset. Ha!"*  .. By 'Ha!' DYM 'Yee-Ha!'?  ;)  But yes, I see what you mean.

Comment: WOW!! You put a lot of time and effort into helping me improve my code. I am dumbfounded at the extra effort you went to. Thank you very much! At first blush, it's going to take me a little time to understand it all, so the next chance I get to devote some attention to it, I' going  to go through it and figure out all the tips you've got treasured away in there.

Comment: I finally had a chance to go through your code edits, and thank you @Hovercraft Full of Eels: VERY much. There are a lot of little tweaks here that I never knew about, and some I knew about but hadn't seen a practical application example of before. I learned a lot about some cool ways to fine-tune and improve my Java coding. Again, thank you very much for the time you invested in helping me.